# Why can I not uncheck my CheckBox?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have three CheckBoxes as below and my problem is that once I have checked the bottom checkbox (cbOnlyUK) I can not then uncheck it. I am unsure why this is the case or how to resolve it so any help is appreciated.

```
<input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="cbNonUK"/>Non-UK<br />
<input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="cbNonEU"/>Non-EU<br />
<input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="cbOnlyUK" onchange="onlyUK()"/>UK Only
```

cbOnlyUK has the following Javascript code attached to it:

```
function onlyUK() { 
    if (document.getElementById("<%= cbOnlyUK.ClientID %>").checked = true)
    {
        document.getElementById("<%= cbNonUK.ClientID %>").checked = false;
        document.getElementById("<%= cbNonEU.ClientID %>").checked = false;
        document.getElementById("<%= cbOnlyEU.ClientID %>").checked = false;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

--- EDIT ---

As pointed out by a few, the problem was the first line of the function which should be:

```
if (document.getElementById("<%= cbOnlyUK.ClientID %>").checked == true)
```

Comment: You mean you can't uncheck it with JavaScript or you can't uncheck it at all?

Comment: First of all, change `if (document.getElementById("<%= cbOnlyUK.ClientID %>").checked = true)` to `if (document.getElementById("<%= cbOnlyUK.ClientID %>").checked == true)` because that if statement is actually checking the checkbox, and NOT if it's true

Comment: I can't uncheck it at all. If I click it once it checks it. If I click it again it does nothing i.e. it stays checked

Comment: @AlonEitan yes, that was it. How stupid of me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On your function "onlyUK" you have a a typo

```
if (document.getElementById("<%= cbOnlyUK.ClientID %>").checked = true)
```

Since you're using `=` instead of `==`, you're applying the true value instead of comparing it. This should be ok

```
if (document.getElementById("<%= cbOnlyUK.ClientID %>").checked == true)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because in your if-statement you need it like this

```
 if (document.getElementById("<%= cbOnlyUK.ClientID %>").checked == true)
```

Instead of

```
if (document.getElementById("<%= cbOnlyUK.ClientID %>").checked = true)
```